# In WDM, will using different tags for ExAllocatePoolWithTag and ExFreePoolWithTag result in memory leak eventhough the allocated memory is freed?

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, device-driver, wdm

Will the below usage result in memory leak? (non-matching tag is used)

```
ptr = (uint*)ExAllocatePoolWithTag (NonPagedPool, 4*sizeof(uint), 'BAC@');

ExFreePoolWithTag (ptr, 'ABC@');
```

Comment: Good question. I'd like to know the answer if you figure it out, or find it elsewhere. My understanding is that the 'tag' is just to make it easier to track allocated memory back to its source (e.g., if your driver is leaking somewhere). I _suspect_ that when freeing, a non-matching tag gets ignored (or just generates a warning in Debug) -- but that's just a guess...